# Getting a error on assigning a variable and a colon

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a text adventure game but when I try running it I get a error on "battle_input = battle_input.lower()" and "if battle_input == "attack":"
Can you tell me whats wrong?

```
def battle(monster):
print "You have encountered a %s" % (str(monster))
while hero_health > 0 or monster.health > 0:
    battle_input = input("Would you like to attack, use magic, use item, or retreat?"
    battle_input = battle_input.lower()
    if battle_input == "attack":
        print "You attack with your %s!" % (weapon)
        damage = random.randint(hero_attack, player_attack + 5)
        print "The %s takes %s damage!" % (monster, str(damage))
        monster.health -= damage
        if monster.health <= 0:
            print "You slayed the %s!" % (monster)
            break
    #add the others
    print "The %s attacks!" % (monster)
    monster_damage = random.randint(monster.attack, monster.attack + 5)
    player_health -= damage
else:
        if monster_health <= 0:
            print "Congratulations!"
        else:
            print "Game over."
            game_over = 1
```

Comment: Missing `)` on the previous line.

Comment: and use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding `input` line:

```
battle_input = input("Would you like to attack, use magic, use item, or retreat?"
#                                                                ----------------^
```

Add that closing parenthesis and Python can make sense of this line and the next again.

Rule of thumb: whenever you encounter a strange `SyntaxError` that doesn't appear to make sense, *check the preceding line* and make sure that all opening parenthesis, brackets, and braces have a matching closing character.